# Laravel: How can I hide duplicate value

Tags: php, laravel

```
$SearchTag = Tag::where(function($query) {

    $query->orWhere('tag', 'like', 'veritatis%');

    $query->orWhere('tag', 'like', 'rem%');

})->with('search_Tags')->get();
```

Comment: what I mean is, is there a function that can remove duplicate in the query or do you have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question completely make sure to provide as much details as you can in future , for now i have provided a solution below, this might work.

```
$SearchTag = Tag::where(function($query) {

  $query->orWhere('tag', 'like', 'veritatis%');
  $query->orWhere('tag', 'like', 'rem%');

})->with('search_Tags')->get();

$uniqueTags = $SearchTag->unique('tag');
return response($uniqueTags);
```

I Haven't tested this , do so and let me know if any errors occur. if it does not works remove the with('search_Tags) from query and check if it works , if it does than you can get 'search_Tags' separately for each SearchTag after getting the unique ones.

Comment: Sorry about the miss conception the thing is I am trying to remove same data if the article have the same tags,distinct function is not working, but, i'll try this first thank you